# AspectJ Around call, including method body after method call

Tags: java, aspectj

so I'm trying to achieve something similar to kotlin coroutines in Java AspectJ

And Currently I'm trying to intercept methods when a method call to Waitable.waitFor() called
And everything in method body after Waitable.waitFor() should be scheduled

But in my current code, it only intercepting the method call, and the method body after that is not included

So I wonder is my pointcut expression code wrong? Or there is any better way to achieve this?

```
@Around("call(* org.imanity.framework.wait.Waitable.waitFor(..))")
public Object waitCall(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    Scheduler.runAfter(() -> joinPoint.proceed(), Long.parseLong(joinPoint.getArgs()[0]));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to capture method body after call.

Imagine you can do it.

1. How it will work with loops?
2. Where local variables will be stored?

PS:There is project Loom that designed to add coroutines to java.

PS: we have to do everything we can to stop that project, it is huge mistake.

Comment: you are right, aspectJ is impossible to achieve this, but i wonder why project loom is a mistake?

Comment: They try to introduce new feature instead of fixing existing one. If they can make new threads cheaper, why they don't just fix old threads.

Comment: understood, i will try to read more doucment about them, thanks for the answers!